# Visual Studio: How to access to items from a class?

Tags: c#, wpf, class

I am trying to build an application. I want my class to get access to items such as Grid, Canvas, Button on my window.

However I can call these items from main only.
I tried to use reference but my attempt had been a complete failure.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="590" Width="855">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Height="428" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="myCanvas" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="647" Background="White">
            <Label Content="Label" Height="29" Name="Label1" Canvas.Left="283" Canvas.Top="0" />
            <Label Content="Label" Height="28" Name="Label2" Canvas.Left="329" Canvas.Top="1" />
            <Rectangle Height="30" Width="30" Fill="#49D8FF00" Canvas.Left="83" Canvas.Top="164" Name="user"></Rectangle>
            <Button Canvas.Left="593" Canvas.Top="6" Content="FindPath" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="88" Click="button1_Click" />
            <Label Canvas.Left="568" Canvas.Top="66" Content="Display Map here" Height="251" Width="253" Name="mapDisplayer" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the XAML code for my program. I want to access to one of these many items.
I tried to use Name of each item to call.
Such as myCanvas, but I get an error saying that the name 'myCanvas' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far.

Comment: Can you show us your class (or some of it)? Did you remember to put the proper `using` statements at the top?

Comment: Is this a VB or C# question?  I am not sure what "Visual Basic C#" is.  Is the C# tag correct?  Perhaps you meant "Visual Studio C#"?  We will definitely need more information and code...

Comment: If they aren't showing up by their name, then you don't have the namespace's correct.

Change x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" to x:Class="WhateverYourNamespaceIs.WhateverYourWindowNameis"

By default, it should look like this:
x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1" if you named nothing and this is your first project with no name.

Comment: @user1143720 - Please post the C# code.  Please format the XAML code you provided us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is your code implemented? I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think you need to get the instance of the main form.

For example

```
class myClass
{
    public myClass(Window1 instance)
    {
        instance.myGrid.Width= 512;

        //Window1 .myGrid.Width= 512; will not work because myGrid is not static.
    }
}

public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1 ()
    {
         myClass m = new myClass(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a separated class.I want this separate class to have a constructor that asks for any Canvas tool in  the MainWindow, so that it can manipulate the Canvas within the class. does it make a sense?

Comment: Then the code I provided is what your looking for. When creating the class, you need to pass 'this' (the current instance) to the class so it can use it.

Comment: What should I be using to access to type Form1?

Comment: Basically, the class gets passed the MainWindow class. If you just type 
Windows1.myCanvas.Width, you will get an error, that is because referencing the class like that only gives you access to the static variables within it. You want to pass the instance so it can use the instance of the class you are currently using. That's what 'this' represents.